# Register Generic Type T in Unity Dependency Injection mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I, am using mvc 5.2 and use the UnityConfig to perform the dependency injection. I have setup the injection as below in **global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        }
```

Now, I have a generic class of Type T as below

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
}
```

Now in the unity config file I want to add a generic class

```
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();            
            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<IHomeService, HomeService>();
            container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<>,GenericRepository)();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```

This gives me an error as below screen shot
[image: error]

I tried to use `typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>)`

This doesn't work for me.
How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: The error message says it all: you are missing the type argument. ￼

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use typeof(IGenericRepository<>),
>   typeof(GenericRepository<>) This doesn't work for me.

Here is how you should register generic types with Unity:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
var obj = container.Resolve<IGenericRepository<object>>();
```

Comment: any thoughts on handling scopes?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
        {
            IQueryable<T> GetAll();
            IQueryable<T> FindByFunc(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
            void AddEntity(T entity);
            void DeleteEntity(T entity);
            void EditEntity(T entity);
            void SaveEntity();
        }

    public class BaseRepository<context, T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class where context : DbContext, new()
        {
            private context _entities = new context();
            public context Context
            {

                get { return _entities; }
                set { _entities = value; }
            }

            public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
            {

                IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
                return query;
            }
    }

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
            BusinessComponent(container);
            DataBaseComponent(container);
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<,>));


            return container;
        }
```

Comment: Provide some explanation to the answer